# "Undefined" when trying to use async/await/promise

Tags: tokens, erc-20, truffle-deployment, async

I'm currently trying to put in the function:

truffle console
truffle (development) > const token = await Token.deployed()

And the result is coming up as undefined. I've started over my DAPP project twice and have reached the same point.

I deployed the contract in separate migration files. I received no error during migration. Related files are shared below:

1_initial_migration.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {   deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

---

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");

module.exports = function (deployer) {   deployer.deploy(Token); };
```

￼

Comment: So apparantly "undefined" doesn't mean that it is undefined you just need to call the variable in the terminal to see the definition! If anyone gets scared when they see undefined it most likely doesn't mean an error :)

Comment: Stamyr,
did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same message for this command? How did you resolve it? Thanks...Raj

Answer (score 1):

Just type the variable you set your promise to assign to and it will output the value to the terminal.